# Unable to mirror AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer on macOS

Tags: macos, avfoundation

I'm using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer (macOS, not iOS) to capture video input from an attached camera. I've setup a capture session and created a UIView to display the image:

`self.captureLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession);
self.playerView.layer = self.captureLayer;`

Everything is working fine, and I see the image from the camera, but now I want to mirror the image (vertically). I'm using a CATransform3DMakeScale:

`self.captureLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0);`

Instead of mirroring the image however, the layer just goes blank (background of the parent view).

I've tried other transforms (e.g. resizes) and they work fine. I've also tried mirroring the superlayer:

`self.captureLayer.superLayer?.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0);`

And this works (although it mirrors the entire window including the title bar!).

Any help appreciated. I believe the transform is correct, but for some reason it's not applying to a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.

Comment: Thanks @manishganvir - really appreciate the answer and code sample. Will try this weekend, however if this does work, I assume it will only provide mirroring across the horizontal access, whereas using CATransform3DMakeScale I can also mirror vertically (which is also used in my app).

Comment: @manishganvir Just ran your sample code - works great. Also found `self.cameraLayer!.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portraitUpsideDown` will provide me with vertically mirroring. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of avcaptureconnection properties to do this.

```
self.cameraLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: frontVideoSession)
self.cameraLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

    if (self.cameraLayer!.connection.isVideoMirroringSupported)
    {
        self.cameraLayer!.connection.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = false
        self.cameraLayer!.connection.isVideoMirrored = true
    }
```

You can read more about this at https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcaptureconnection/1389172-isvideomirrored

---

The **isVideoMirrored** flag allows you to choose whether you want to mirror the video or not. If it is set to true, it will mirror the video, if it set to false, it will not mirror. In order for you to use this flag, you must set automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring flag to false.

---

Wrote an example code for you https://github.com/manishganvir/mac-camera-mirror-example. Please check the same. Snippet below

```
do {
         let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camDevice)


          VideoSession.addInput(input)

          self.cameraLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: VideoSession)
          print(" connection " , self.cameraLayer!.connection.isVideoMirroringSupported , self.cameraLayer!.connection.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring);

          if (self.cameraLayer!.connection.isVideoMirroringSupported)
          {
                 self.cameraLayer!.connection.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = false
                 self.cameraLayer!.connection.isVideoMirrored = true
          }
          self.cameraLayer!.frame = self.view.bounds

          self.view.layer = self.cameraLayer!
          self.view.wantsLayer = true

          VideoSession.startRunning()
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this for mirroring after adding layer to sublayer (no other sublayer) :

```
yourview.layer!.sublayers?[0].transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```